# Rails + Spree: Where are the controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I was given a legacy app and in my log when I load a page I see this:

`Processing ContentController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-14 17:45:51) [GET]`

However, I can't seem to find it even when I do a CTRL + Shift + F in my text editor.

I am pretty clueless on how to use Spree. Could anyone tell me how the routes and the controllers work? There are so many extensions in this app but I can't seem to find out which route file is handling what, and the same goes for the controllers.

Same goes for this:

`Processing TaxonsController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-14 17:46:22) [GET]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controllers are in the spree gem.

Try typing the following command in your console in your rails project directory:

```
bundle show spree
```

The controllers you're looking for should be located in the subdirectories underneath that path.

You can familiarize yourself with [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) and how it loads dependencies that are specified in the Gemfile.  That should make things a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks gmac. How would I run this in Rails 2 + Ruby 1.8.7, where there is no Gemfile? And if everything is contained within the spree gem, how will I customize it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this was Rails 2.  Before bundler, it was a dark time...  Your gems will either be installed in to vendor/gems, or in to some directory (generally specified by $GEM_HOME).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of spree are  you using?

What I like to do is go to the [Spree Github Page](https://github.com/spree/spree), select the the branch/tag I'm using and search the code from there.

Protip: In github press 't' on your keyboard and start typing the name of the file you're looking for.

If you want a more permanent solution, consider cloning their project on your local machine and browse the code that way.

Comment: so do I have to edit the spree controller directly if I want to make changes?